# Can I use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.User.LoginName as login for custom Identity authentication?

Tags: authentication, provider-hosted-app, azure

As the title suggests, I am doing a SharePoint Provider-hosted app that will be deployed to Microsoft Azure. I implemented security with custom Authentication class which references Owin namespaces.

One of our requirements were two authentication methods:

1. a custom forms-based one
2. a user-identifier is read from CSOM context and if that identifier exists in my custom accounts table, the user is also logged in.

I decided to use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.User.LoginName as my identifier but I don't know if this will be unique/secure? What if the user changes his/her email address? Will it reflect in this property?